# Printer file concurrent access

Tags: java, ubuntu, printing, io

I'm developing system,that often prints reports, and always is checking the status of printer (Low on paper, Out of paper etc...). I've implemented class, that queries printer file (/dev/usb/lp0) for status as written in printers (Swecoin TTP2030) manual, here is a code:

```
 public class PrinterStatusEnquier {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(PrinterStatusEnquier.class);

    private static byte[] PAPER_NEAR_END_ENQUIRY = {0x1B, 0x05, 0x02}; 
    private static byte[] STATUS_ENQUIRY = {0x1B, 0x05, 0x01}; 

    private static String PRINTER_DEVICE = 
               PropertiesManager.getInstance().getApplicationProperty("printer.device.file");

    public static PaperStatus enquiryPaperStatus() throws IOException {
        logger.debug("In method enquiryPaperStatus()...");

        RandomAccessFile device = null;
        try
        {
            device = new RandomAccessFile(PRINTER_DEVICE, "rw");

            device.write(PAPER_NEAR_END_ENQUIRY);
            int response = device.readByte();

            return PaperStatus.getStatus(response);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Error while opening file: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        } finally {
            if (device != null) {
                logger.debug("Closing file...");
                device.close();
            }
        }
    }

    public static PrinterStatus enquiryPrinterStatus() throws IOException {
        logger.debug("In method enquiryPrinterStatus()...");

        RandomAccessFile device = null;
        try {
            device = new RandomAccessFile(PRINTER_DEVICE, "rw");

            device.write(STATUS_ENQUIRY);

            byte[] response = new byte[2];
            device.read(response);

            return PrinterStatus.getStatus(response);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Error while opening file: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        } finally {
            if (device != null) {
                logger.debug("Closing file...");
                device.close();
            }
        }       
    }
```

And out of my system this code works great. But when I integrate it in system, it starts to raise a lot of IOExceptions. I noticed that it happens when printer prints something, and in this moment I try to get status. Some times I get exception (File not found), and in this case I can check printer file like that - `file.canWrite()` But sometimes I can get exception (Device or resource busy) or (Input/Output error), and in this case `file.canWrite()` won't help. The worst thing is, that printer status enquirer not only throws exceptions, it can lock printer's file for some time. It still prints, but unavailable for enquirer.

Does exist a way to enquiry printer file while it's printing? Or maybe exists a way how to check if printer file is available. Please help!

P.S.: System is Ubuntu 12.10

Updae: I'm printing via DocPrintJob object: `job.print();` I also tryed to print invoking shell command:

```
Process p;
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cat output.pdf | lpr");
p.waitFor();
```

But I faced same issues.

Comment: Your printing code does not seems to be synchronized with the reading code.Can u show your printing code above if it is in java? And what d u mean by "out of my system" ?

Comment: By "out of my system" I mean that I compiled this code in .jar, and invoked jar in system, and it worked without exceptions.

Comment: So what is your problem? Ultimately anyways you are going to use the jar to run the code!

Comment: The problem is that, when I tested this jar, printer was idle. That is why everything went well.